# I need to dynamically fill an NSMutableDictionary with other NSMutableDictionarys as they are created

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I figured the way to do this was to create the main dictionary (called mainDictionary), and then have another dictionary (called tempDictionary) and fill up tempDictionary one with the values as I get them. Then, add tempDictionary as a value into the main dictionary. This works, but then I need to clear tempDictionary so that I can refill it again, and then add that as another value in the main dictionary. The thing is, when I clear tempDictionary, it also erases those values from the main dictionary. Here's my code:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [tempDictionary setObject:@"apple" forKey:@"myFruit"];

 [mainDictionary setObject:tempDictionary forKey:@"sample4"];
 [tempDictionary removeAllObjects];
```

So apparently I need to use a different method, or somehow "save" the mainDictionary before clearing tempDictionary. The tempDictionary needs to be dynamically updated and then fill the mainDictionary.. is there a way to do this? There will be hundreds of "samples" that need to be added, so I can't just have a bunch of tempDictionarys created at runtime.

Comment: You notice a pattern?  There is only one "tempDictionary" object, and you can't erase its contents and expect the values to still be there.  Consider creating a *new* "tempDictionary" for every cycle.

Comment: I can't do that, because of the way the tempdictionary is filled. It's constantly filled when a seperate function gets hit. It needs to be global.

Comment: That makes no sense.  If you can empty it, you can replace it.

Comment: ..no, dude. I could spend 5 min explaining specifically why it doesn't work for this problem, but thats a waste of time.

Comment: Yes, you're right -- it's a waste of time for me to try to convince you why you're wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the temp dictionary contents (as added to main) to remain intact when you remove all the objects from the temp dictionary you should copy it before adding it to the main dictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tempDictionary setObject:@"apple" forKey:@"myFruit"];

[mainDictionary setObject:[tempDictionary copy] forKey:@"sample4"];
[tempDictionary removeAllObjects];
```

The alternative is to reuse tempDictionary but to do

```
tempDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

to create a new temp dictionary with the same name every time you begin a new collection - this is very different to

```
[tempDictionary removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: perfect! thanks. I'll accept the answer in 3 min when it lets me.

Comment: That's stupid -- unnecessarily copying the contents from one dictionary to the other.  Just create a new "tempDictionary".

Comment: As I said in the main post, creating a new tempdictionary doesn't work. Adam understood the question perfectly.

Comment: Creating a new dictionary is more efficient and does achieve the same. It might be convenient or not depending on the current state of your code. I don't know if a solution is stupid just because it could be more optimal but Hot Licks is right - added to answer.